# Binary tree - Delete nodes whose level is greater or equal than given one

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As title says, I need to write function that deletes all nodes from binary tree that have level greater or equal than given one in function as parameter, for example, I need to delete all nodes that are level 2 and higher.

But, I cannot add any attributes to nodes or use stack, queue, etc, or any other structure.

Any ideas on this? I'll appreciate it very much.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of Node and deleteNode is up to you:

```
   void deleteLevel(Node *node, size_t level)
    {
        if(node->right)
        {
            if(level == 0)
            {
                deleteNode(node->right);
                node->right = nullptr;
            }
            else deleteLevel(node->right, level - 1);
        }
        if(node->left)
        {
            if(level == 0)
            {
                deleteNode(node->left);
                node->left = nullptr;
            }
            else deleteLevel(node->left, level - 1);
        }
    }

    ...

    deleteLevel(aNode, levlOfANode);
```

The implementation of Node and deleteNode is up to you.